# Access to the script '/path/to/script.php' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)

Tags: php, macos, nginx, homebrew

before let me list what I have tried:

- [This Answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/402009/fastcgi-error-access-to-the-script-denied)
- chmoded /Users/user/portal3 to 777 to see if executes
- Created two pools one with root and another with current user
- googled
- entered ##php in freenode
- and lot of other ideas.

i have a problem executing php code on a subdirectory inside my home directory.
On Nginx i get this

```
2016/08/23 09:13:40 [error] 39170#0: *13 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script 
'/Users/user/portal3' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading
response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request:
"GET /portal/v3/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "localhost"
```

On php-fpm this shows

```
[23-Aug-2016 09:13:40] WARNING: [pool dev] child 8305 said into stderr: "NOTICE: Access to the script '/Users/user/portal3' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)"
```

I have tried everything but I don't have any success running php with Nginx / PHP-FPM on Mac

Ngnix adn PHP-FPM runs as root

PHP-FPM it's configured with two pools:

- [www]: run as root and works fine, execute php code but their www-root subdirectory is in /var/www
- [dev] pool that runs as my current user on MacOS X, listen on port 9001, and is configured to run code in /Users/user/portal3.

### php-fpm.ini

```
[dev]
user=user
group=staff
listen=127.0.0.1:9001
listen.mode = 0666
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 10
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s
pm.status_path = /status_user
catch_workers_output = yes
security.limit_extensions = .php
```

### default (on sites-available) Nginx

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    ###root /var/www/;
    access_log   /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/default.access.log  main;
    access_log   /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/default.scripts.log  scripts;

    location /portal/v3 {
        alias /Users/user/portal3;
        location ~  ^/portal/v3/(.+\.php)(/.*)$ {
            #alias /Users/user/portal3;
            index index.php;

            # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
            fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";

            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$2;#$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

    }

    location = /info {
        allow   127.0.0.1;
        deny    all;
        rewrite (.*) /.info.php;
    }

    location / {
        root /var/www/;
        index        index.php index.html index.htm;
        include   /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm;
    }

    error_page  404     /404.html;
    error_page  403     /403.html;
}
```

i have installed everything using homebrew. Now i'm running out of ideas, i came here to get some help.

Comment: Did you `see security.limit_extensions`?

Comment: yes ... i have triple cheked

Comment: Then after that, what did you change to resolve the issue?

Comment: What's the value of `security.limit_extensions` in your config?

Comment: @muton security.limit_extensions = .php

Comment: @Rafael ... so only files with the extensions `.php` are allowed, and you're trying to access one with no extension.

Comment: You need the `index index.php` directive inside the `location /portal/v3` location block. Otherwise your web server doesn't know to use `index.php` as the default index file when pointed to `/portal/v3`. Also, there's no reason to nest those location blocks. It actually doesn't do what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your [PHP-FPM config](http://php.net/install.fpm.configuration#security-limit-extensions) you have a directive called `security.limit_extensions`

> Limits the extensions of the main script FPM will allow to parse. This can prevent configuration mistakes on the web server side. You should only limit FPM to .php extensions to prevent malicious users to use other extensions to execute php code. Default value: .php.

In your case, because your `location` block doesn't contain an `index` directive, nginx doesn't know to use `index.php` as the default index file when the path points to `/Users/user/portal3`. Instead it attempts to execute it as a PHP script, and PHP-FPM raises the security restriction that `/Users/user/portal3` does not have a .php extension.

Your location block should look more like this...

```
location /portal/v3 {
    alias /Users/user/portal3;
    index index.php;
    location ~  ^/portal/v3/(.+\.php)(/.*)$ {
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$2;#$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Comment: Or, a better idea, give the file an allowed extension so you don't randomly allow every file to try to be interpreted by PHP :P

Comment: well, really there is no script named portal3 , its a subdirectory ... all the site is configured to make a url friendly website... in fact inside portal3 there is a index.php that resolves everything ... so maybe it's not exactly what i'm looking for

Comment: That would be a web server configuration issue then. Because according to this your web server doesn't understand that this is a directory and as such didn't attempt to rewrite the request URI to point to `/Users/user/portal3/index.php`. Instead, it actually tried to execute `/Users/user/portal3` as a PHP script. So more likely is the case that your web server's rewrite rule is broken.

Comment: $document_root$2;#$fastcgi_script_name; or SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem earlier today. I just renamed my file extension from .phtml to .php to fix it immediately.

I later changed my `security.limit_extensions` setting in my php config file (something like /etc/php/fpm/php-fpm.conf) to allow .phtml (See line below)

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .phtml
```

This line might also be commented with a `#`, if thats the case just uncomment the line by removing the `#`.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to add the FastCGI Parameters PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED.

```
fastcgi_param    DOCUMENT_ROOT      /var/www/html;
fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME    /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param    PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param    PATH_TRANSLATED    $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
```

Hope this helps any those who need this too.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue resolved in my case, as we had multiple php-fpm conf files got loaded and in one of them, ***pm.status*** was commented out.

uncommented the line and it started working.