# How to edit security.limit_extensions on Azure App Service on Linux

Tags: php, azure, nginx, service

How are you able to change the security.limit_extensions directive on Azure App Service for Linux when running PHP 8 or 8.1 (Nginx rather than Apache)?

I have changed all of the usual places (including /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf) but none are having an impact. I understand this will need a bash script to update each restart, and have this working for php.ini values, but cannot get this to work for FPM values. Currently have the following error when parsing HTML as PHP, with NGINX blocks seemingly setup correctly:

```
[ERROR]  NOTICE: Access to the script '/home/site/wwwroot/login.html' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)
```

Comment: you've done all the things and what not, but onfortunately missed to actual write what the original configuration was, which changes you did apply and which setting exactly is still causing the error. so its not really clear what your asking for. please [edit] in all the details. Also _cf._ https://stackoverflow.com/q/39104150/367456 - and which linux distro and version do you have in use?

Comment: I need to be able to edit security.limit_extensions on an Azure App Service. It doesn't seem possible, even once added to the config, it doesn't do anything different.

Comment: Please add **all** the details to the question. Configuration file paths etc., even it did not work out well for you yet. Otherwise users who know won't be able to identify if they know an answer to the question or not.

Comment: The details are there, this is an Azure App Service, so there is no configuration. It is a standard setup for those using Azure heavily.

Comment: Well then I'd recommend to contact the vendor of the system for your support options with that software product, and further vote to close as off-topic as it's about using a specific software. and not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably already created a custom nginx config file and set up /home/site/startup.sh to copy it in place and reload nginx.

The principal is the same.

```
cp /usr/local/php-fpm.d/www.conf /home/site
```

Edit /home/site/www.conf and comment out the security.limit_extensions line and add some extensions:

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .php7 .html .htm
```

Edit /home/site/startup.sh to add the following line before the nginx reload:

```
cp /home/site/www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

Restart your web app.

Comment: Hi Philip,

Thank you, but this is what I have already put in place. However, the same error message is returned. Do you have this working on your setup at all?

Comment: This doesn't work - unfortunately the original pool conf file is respawned or replaced.